# how to pass useState variable value to array of object field for INSERT data react.js and mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

**I have a billing form and in this i have some product details that admin can fill these details but 1 field called "BillID" i want to directly pass   a variable to it that contain 'Bill ID + 1' value as a default value.

**This is My Code:-

```
  const [BillIdFetch, setBillIdFetch] = useState();

 useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getLastBill_Id").then(( res ) => {
      setBillIdFetch(res.data[0].Bill_Id + 1);
    });
  }, []);

 console.log("===>>>> Testing BillIdFetch ",BillIdFetch) //**I check in this variable value stored perfectly.

const [Product_Details, setProduct_Details] = useState([
    {
      index: Math.random(),
      billId : BillIdFetch, //**I want 'BllIdFetch' value pass to this state variable.
      prodId: "",
      qty: "",
      price: "",
      prod_SrNo: "",
      discount_price: "",
      proData_warranty: "",
    },
  ]);
```

In 'BillIdFetch' i got correct id + 1 value and i also use this value for displaying Bill no. in form column. but when i set this value to 'billId' it shows like this :- {billId: undefined}

**This is post request to the server.**

In this a pass 'Produt_Details' array of object to it.

```
 const config = {
        header: {
          "Content type": "appication/json",
        },
      };

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/billing_data",
        { p_value: Product_Details },
        config
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to check when `BillIdFetch` changes, and then set the correct state value for `Product_Details`. In your current code, the code for setting the value of `Product_Details?` will run before the fetching.

To solve this, use a `useEffect` hook with `BillIdFetch` as a dependency, thus, this code will run when `BillIdFetch` changes.

It could look something like this:

```js
const [Product_Details, setProduct_Details] = useState([]);
const [BillIdFetch, setBillIdFetch] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getLastBill_Id").then(( res ) => {
     setBillIdFetch(res.data[0].Bill_Id + 1);
   });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (billIdFetch === undefined) return;
    setProduct_Details([{
      index: Math.random(),
      billId : BillIdFetch,
      prodId: "",
      qty: "",
      price: "",
      prod_SrNo: "",
      discount_price: "",
      proData_warranty: "",
    }])
}, [billIdFetch])
```